# Axis labels according to DIN461

Tags: pgfplots

DIN461 requires to put the unit of the axis between the last two ticks of an axis, see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_461 (sorry only in german, but the lower two images make it clear, I think)

Is there an "easy" way to get the positions of the ticks for this purpose?

Comment: I can't see the placement you have described in the text in the Wiki page. Plus I doubt that someone would come up with this norm as a standard. It's all too context dependent

Comment: @JoeyD: It should be possible to implement this reasonably easily. However, if your goal really is to follow the standard, it would be helpful to have access to the actual standard, not just Wikipedia's interpretation of it (the examples on the page are not very coherent). Do you have access to the standard? Or are you only trying to get the placement of the unit label between the last two tick labels, without caring about the rest of the standard?

Comment: The latter at the moment, at the moment I'm hunting for the actual standard.

Comment: As it stands, I'm with Jake here: it's not that easy to answer based on second-hand info. What we really need is a plot/code to work from (MWE) and a clear description of what needs to be changed.